# How to access the input value of children component from parents component in ReactJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem with the access of the input value, I used here is **.map()**.
Here is the code, `<QuestionLabel/>`is the children component. `projectsData.projectDetail` is an available data

```
//..
{projectsData.projectDetail.questions.map((question) => (
                    <QuestionLabel
                        questionTitle={question}  
                    />
                ))}


//child component
const QuestionLabel=(props)=>{
    const [answerInput, setAnswerInput] = React.useState("");
     return(
         <div className="contact">
            <form  className="contact-form" autocomplete="off">
                <div class="contact-form-group">
                    <label 
                        for="name" 
                        class="contact-form-label"
                    >
                        {props.questionTitle}
                    </label>
                    <input 
                        id="name" 
                        type="text" 
                        class="contact-form-input"
                        value={answerInput}
                        onChange={(answer) => setAnswerInput(answer.target.value)}

                />
                </div>
                
            </form>
     </div>
     );
 }
 export default QuestionLabel;
```

Comment: the parent component should be the one who owns that state, not the child. The parent should know the childs value and pass that value to the child, and it should also pass a callback for the child to call when the user types more in the input. This is the way data is supposed to flow in React. You can read more in the docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Comment: What do you mean when you say ```problem with the access of the input value```? Do you mean this line ```onChange={(answer) => setAnswerInput(answer.target.value)}```  doesn't work?

Comment: The problem that I think OP is having is that he has rendered a list of child component in the parent one. And now he wants to access the value inputs from the parent component. Using lifting state up will let the parent controls all the state of the child component. Meanwhile, imo, the OP just wants to access those input values of each child component from the parent one

Comment: yea, Mark is right! BTW, I solved that. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many way to get value from child component for parent component. You can call a function pass from parent to children to set `value` for `parent state` when it's changed. Exmaple:

```
const ParentComponent =(props)=>{
    const [valueFromChild, setValueFromChild] = useState('');

    return <>
        {valueFromChild}
        <QuestionLabel questionTitle={'Title'} setValueFromChild={setValueFromChild}/>
        </>
}

const QuestionLabel=(props)=>{
    const [answerInput, setAnswerInput] = React.useState("")

    useEffect(() => {
        props.setValueFromChild(answerInput);
    }, [answerInput]);

    return(
        <div className="contact">
            <form  className="contact-form" autoComplete="off">
                <div class="contact-form-group">
                    <label
                        for="name"
                        class="contact-form-label"
                    >
                        {props.questionTitle}
                    </label>
                    <input
                        id="name"
                        type="text"
                        class="contact-form-input"
                        value={answerInput}
                        onChange={(answer) => setAnswerInput(answer.target.value)}
                    />
                </div>

            </form>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you need to have the input state up in the parent.

Since you are mapping through questions array to render the `QuestionLabel` we can try this...

```
//..
const ParentComponent = () => {
  const [answers, setAnswers] = React.useState({})

  useEffect(() => {
    projectsData.projectDetail.questions.forEach((_, i) => {
      setAnswers(previousAnswers => {...previousAnswers, ["name" + i]: ""})
    })
  }, [])

  const handleAnswers = (e) => {
    setAnswers(previousAnswers => {...previousAnswers, [e.target.name]: [e.target.value]})
  }
//..
```

then

```
//..
{
  projectsData.projectDetail.questions.map((question, i) => {
    return (
      <QuestionLabel questionTitle={question} inputName={"name" + i} answers={answers} handleAnswers={handleAnswers} />
    )
  })
}
```

and finally...

```
//child component
const QuestionLabel=(props)=>{

     return(
         <div className="contact">
            <form  className="contact-form" autocomplete="off">
                <div class="contact-form-group">
                    <label 
                        for={props.inputName}
                        class="contact-form-label"
                    >
                        {props.questionTitle}
                    </label>
                    <input 
                        id={props.inputName}
                        name={props.inputName} 
                        type="text" 
                        class="contact-form-input"
                        value={answers[props.inputName]}
                        onChange={handleAnswers}
                />
                </div>
                
            </form>
     </div>
     );
 }
 export default QuestionLabel;
```

Comment: I modified my answer to handle the `.map` in parent